# How do I update a list using MongoDB and Spring's repository?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document like below:

```
{
  myDocument: 
  {
     _id: (Auto-generated)
     someField: "Hello world",
     targetField: ["Steve", "Bill"]
  }
    
}
```

Also, I have a repository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<MyDocument, String> {

}
```

**My question is**: "How do I add a new data inside of targetField without finding it locally? Because if my list gets too big, I don't want to load it, but only insert something new inside of it."

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `MongoTemplate`, `Query` and `Update` by `spring data mongodb`

- `Update.addToSet` Add items to a Set (non-duplicatable)
- `Update.push` Append items to an Array (duplicatable)

```java
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.*;

@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

```java
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(idToUpdate));
Update update = new Update();
update.addToSet("targetField", "newValue");
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "collectionName");
```

- To get result document, using `FindAndModifyOptions`

```java
FindAndModifyOptions options = FindAndModifyOptions.options()
        .returnNew(true);
TargetClass result = mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, options, TargetClass.class, "collectionName");
```

- Add multiple value

```java
update.addToSet("targetField")
    .each("value1", "value2");
update.push("targetField")
    .each("value1", "value2");
```

- Remove item at `position`

```java
update.pop("targetField", position);
```

- Remove item by `value`

```java
update.pull("targetField", "value");
```

- Remove multiple items

```java
update.pullAll("targetField", new Object[]{"value1", "value2"});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$addToSet`

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: "1"
},
{
  "$addToSet": {
    targetField: {
      $each: [
        "Steve",
        "Sam"
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  new: true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/25wLIH7fWye)